# Apache 2.4 issue on proxypass balancing on two BalancerMember [Weblogic 12c]

Tags: apache, weblogic, load-balancing, proxypass, internal-load-balancer

I have an Apache 2.4.12 on a dedicated machine (RedHat 6.x) that must balance on another machine with two Weblogic Managed Servers (port: 9101 and 9102. Weblogic 12c on RedHat 6.x) where I have deployed the application "Pega".

I have implemented the configuration below on the Apache VirtualHost (myvirtualhost.conf) but if I have both BalancerMember active it doesn't work. If I comment one of the two BalancerMember it works fine.

Do you have any suggestion to fix it?

thanks in advance for your collaboration

```
<VirtualHost myvirtualhost:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

   #Server certificate
   SSLCertificateFile /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/ssl/xxx.cer

   #chiave privata del server:
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/ssl/xxx.key

   #chain del certificato del server:
   SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/ssl/xxx.crt

   #Certificate Authority (CA):
   #SSLCACertificateFile /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/ssl/xxx.crt

    ################################

   <Proxy balancer://mybalancing>
       BalancerMember https://myweblogicserver:9101
       BalancerMember https://myweblogicserver:9102
   </Proxy>

    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyPreserveHost on 

##########Disable URL ############
ProxyPass  /myexcludedpath !
##################################

    ProxyPass "/" "balancer://mybalancing/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "balancer://mybalancing/"

</VirtualHost>
```

Edit:
Yes i set correctly parameters.
I reach the login page (both when it works and when it doesn't) but when it doesn't work, if i enter my credential,  i see:

```
Status  fail
Message There has been an issue; please consult your system administrator
Operator ID Unauthenticated or not available
Requestor ID    No ID available
Timestamp   Thu Feb 25 12:37:36 CET 2016
Engine Version  PegaRULES 7.10 ML9 (coreAssemblyCached_719_730)
```

But if i comment one of the BalancerMember:

```
<Proxy balancer://mybalancing>
   # BalancerMember https://myweblogicserver:9101
     BalancerMember https://myweblogicserver:9102
</Proxy>
```

It works fine.

So i guess i miss something in the declaration of 'balancer' , or maybe i miss some directive..

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT2:
Yes the session replication works well between the two servers. I'm able to login using a direct URL to a server (actually a Node in a server, the machine is the same, what changes is the port : 9101 and 9102) and then switch the other server (other node) maintaining my current session..
I guess it's some directive of proxypass but its the first time i face it

Comment: What do you see when it does not work? Did you set the WebLogic FrontEnd Host and Port parameters on your managed nodes?

Comment: I edited my initial question

Comment: Is session replication working between these two servers. Can you login using a direct URL and then switch the other server maintaining your current session?

Comment: I edited again. I guess this is not the right wait to answer, but it's one of the first time for me..so sorry... should i use 'Answer your question' ? i wouldn't like to use Add comment cause maybe not all people will see.. should you maybe use Answer my question instead of Comment'? Sorry again, please guide me to a correct use if i'm not doing well :)

Comment: Editing the question is the correct way. Answers should be solutions to the main question only. So you are doing it right. :)

Comment: Thanks :) so don't you have any answer? only comments? :):) If you need some other explanations, i will be glad to edit again my question ;)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any other ideas on this. I always use the WebLogic Web Server plugins instead. https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/PLGWL/overview.htm#PLGWL391

Comment: Ok, don't worry. Could you post a configuration similar to mine but using WebLogic Web Server plugins? It could be very helpful for me, maybe i can switch to your approach but i would really like to start with a base configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To use the WebLogic Web Server plugins, these are the basic steps:

1. Download the .so file and copy to /etc/httpd/modules.
2. Create a file called /etc/httpd/conf.d/weblogic.conf with the following content:

```html
LoadModule weblogic_module modules/mod_wl_24.so

<IfModule weblogic_module>
    WebLogicCluster myweblogicserver:9101,myweblogicserver:9102
    DebugConfigInfo ON
    MatchExpression * 
</IfModule>
```